# How to set focus on Select2 4.0 in tags mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2-4

Wondering if it's possible to set the focus for a select2 (v4.0) control when  `{ tags: true }` is used? I've tried `$(element).focus()`, `$(element).trigger('click')` and `$(element).trigger('focus')` to no avail.

... or ...

The reason I'm being forced to try and set focus is that it's lost when I unbind the change event, perform an action on the values and then rebind the change event. When I do that, which I need to do every time a new value is entered, I have to click back into the textbox to enter the next value. When I don't unbind, I can just continue to type a value, hit enter, type another value, hit enter and repeat which is the desired (default) behavior. Code I'm using:

```
element.off('change');

element.select2({
    tags: true,
    data: values
});

element.select2('val', values);

element.on('change', function (e) {
    observable.multipleValuesChanged(e);
});
```

Maybe it's not possible or potentially a bug with select2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
element.data('select2').$container.find('.select2-search__field').focus();
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsd72094/)